# How are entropy and Gini Impurity related?

Tags: entropy, gini

I know the differences between entropy and Gini impurity and why we use Gini in order to construct trees. But I would like to find some relation between those two measures. It leads me to one particular question:

*Are there any two distributions X and Y such that entropy of X is greater than the entropy of Y but the Gini impurity of X is smaller than the Gini impurity of Y?*

Answer (score 6):

**The answer depends on the distribution:** specifically, on whether more than two of the probabilities are nonzero.

---

For a discrete distribution with nonzero probabilities $\mathbb{P}=(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n)$ (where $n=\infty$ is possible), the entropy (in natural units) is

$$H(\mathbb P) = -\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \log(p_i)$$

and the Gini Impurity is

$$G(\mathbb P) = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i(1-p_i).$$

#### Case 1: $n=2$

When $n=2$ there are just two probabilities, which I will express as $p_1=p$ and $p_2 = 1-p$ because they must sum to unity.  In this case

$$H(\mathbb P) = -p\log(p) - (1-p)\log(1-p)$$

and

$$G(\mathbb P) = p(1-p) + (1-p)p = 2p(1-p)$$

Values of $G$ in this case must lie between $0$ and $1/2.$  Given such a value $g,$ we can solve

$$p(g) = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 \pm \sqrt{1-2g}\right)$$

and plug that into $H$ to give two values.  They will be equal to each other, yielding a unique corresponding entropy.  Thus $H$ is a function of $G$ in this case.  Here's its graph:

[image: Figure 1]

Because the graph is strictly increasing, *the orderings given by $H$ and $G$ are equivalent.*

#### Case 2: $n\ge 3$

With more than two (nonzero) probabilities, it is possible to find exceptions.  For instance, let $\mathbb{P}_1 = (1/16, 7/16, 1/2)$ and $\mathbb{P}_2 = (1/8, 1/4, 5/8).$  Then you can compute these values of $H$ and $G$:

$$\begin{array}{lrr} \text{Distribution} & G & H \\ \hline
\mathbb{P}_1 & 0.55& 0.88  \\
\mathbb{P}_2 & 0.53& 0.90 
\end{array}$$

**They show a reversal of the ordering.**

Generally, here are the possible values of $(G(\mathbb{P}), H(\mathbb{P}))$ for all distributions $\mathbb{P}$ with three nonzero probabilities:

[image: Figure 2]

Any pair of distributions will form two dots in the gray area.  *When those dots are oriented negatively--that is, one is to the right and below the other--the orderings are reversed.*  The preceding example corresponds to the two orange points.

This exhibits a *relation,* not a function.  You can see, for instance, that when the entropy is approximately $0.64$, the Gini Impurity could be anywhere from around $0.35$ to almost $0.5.$

Nevertheless, there is an *approximate* monotonic relationship between $G$ and $H$ in this case, as shown by the thinness of the gray area.  The additional flexibility with larger $n$ indicates the relationship between $G$ and $H$ will grow even more tenuous as $n$ increases, though.

Because $H$ and $G$ are continuous functions and can be continuously extended to include zero probabilities, for larger $n$ (interpreted as the maximum number of nonzero probabilities in a distribution) it will be possible to find similar examples simply by setting all but three of the probabilities to zero. **Using Lagrange multipliers, we can work out formulas for the range of possible entropies $H$ for any given $n$ and Gini Impurity value $g.$**

- The smallest entropies are attained by distributions having $k$ probabilities of $q$ and one probability of $1-kq$ where $k = \lceil g/(1-g)\rceil$ is the smallest possible number for which $g$ is a feasible Gini Impurity.  The value $q$ is the solution of a quadratic equation, given by $$q = \frac{1 - \sqrt{\Delta(g)}}{k+1};\quad \Delta(g) = 1 - g\frac{k+1}{k}.$$  Notice that $q$ is less than the average of the positive probabilities, $1/(k+1).$ These distributions therefore have a "spike" of probability $1-kq$ and the rest is spread among the minimal number $k$ of other values in order to attain a Gini Impurity of $g.$
- The largest entropies are attained by distributions having $k=n-1$ probabilities of $q$ and one probability of $1-(n-1)q.$  This time $q$ is the other root of the same quadratic equation, $$q = \frac{1 + \sqrt{\Delta(g)}}{n}.$$  Now $q$ slightly exceeds the average probability of $1/n.$ These distributions spread the total probability as evenly as possible over all $n$ values but decrease one of them in order to attain a Gini Impurity of $g.$

Here is a plot of ranges of $H$ as a function of $G$ and $n.$  The additional possibilities for larger $H$ are colored by $n.$  As $n$ grows arbitrarily large, eventually the entire gray area is filled in to arbitrarily high values.  Thus, in general *the only possible simultaneous values of $(G,H)$ that are excluded are those lying beneath the lower (black) curve.*

[image: Figure 3]